# mdwlist enumerate changes from Roman to Arabic after suspend

Tags: enumerate

In LaTeX, I am using the [`enumerate`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate) and [`mdwlist`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mdwlist) packages to create an enumerated list with a pause in the middle, using the suspend/resume commands. I want Roman numerals counting the list items, which I specify by supplying the option `[(i)]` to the `enumerate` environment.

The problem is that after the suspend/resume, the list resumes with Arabic numerals counting the list items, instead of Roman.

If I supply the option `[(i)]` to the resume command, it gives a compile error.

References to the list items also come out as mixed Roman/decimal.

Does anyone know how to fix this, and keep Roman everywhere?

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{mdwlist}

\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}[(i)] % option [(i)] indicates Roman
    \item\label{itemi} First item % Roman
  \suspend{enumerate}
  Text between suspend and resume commands
  \resume{enumerate}[(i)]
    \item\label{itemii} Second item % decimal
  \end{enumerate}
  Ref to first item: ``\ref{itemi}''. Ref to second item: ``\ref{itemii}''.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) instead. It allows you to `resume*` which resumes a list based on the previous settings:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]% roman enumeration
  \item\label{itemi} First item
\end{enumerate}
Text between suspend and resume commands
\begin{enumerate}[resume*]
  \item\label{itemii} Second item
\end{enumerate}
Ref to first item: ``\ref{itemi}''. Ref to second item: ``\ref{itemii}''.
\end{document}
```

`resume*` effectively does `resume,label=(\roman*)` for the options. However, you can use the latter if you wish to update the formatting/options upon a resume.

Comment: Even simpler is `resume*`. With it there is no need to define the label again.

Comment: @JavierBezos: Thanks; I missed that from the documentation.